# Storing books in a database

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema

I want to create a system that stores books (and some other documents). Users will be able to log into the system where they can either see a list of all books or enter some search string and get a list of the books containing the search string. My problem is that I don´t know how I should go about storing my books. The books obv have to be searchable and the search needs to return the books ID, Name, and preferable page. Anything more like the text surrounding the search term would be a nice extra.

Some facts that might help you help me get the best answer.

- The database does not have to be free. If SQL Server or an Oracle DB will help me than I´m all for that.
- The books will be about ~100 (2-600 pages)
- The documents will be about ~1000 (10-50 pages)
- Adding books and documents will be a slow process that will happen infrequently so any type of re-indexing of tables does not need to be fast.
- I have not decided how to search the documents. I do need my search results to be ranked based on relevance somehow. This might become a source of another question in the future

Comment: Do you want to index the whole content of each book and make that searchable?

Comment: Do you want to the soft-copy of the books to be stored in the database or just the meta-data about the books?

Comment: You're essentially asking how to create a repository of very large documents and still be capable of searching them. I'm not sure that a traditional database is the way to go. But I am fairly sure that you probably want to use an existing solution rather than write your own framework. For example, you might want to use Lucene for the search.

Comment: Are you asking which database you should use (E.G. SQL Server) or do you want information on how to structure the tables to store this information?

Comment: How I store the books does not matter as long I get the results I need. It can be either actual copies or meta-data if that is sufficient. My first thought was to get some good table structure that would optimize my search by given some answers here RDBMS does not seem to be a good choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use a RDBMS database. RDBMS are good for storing relational data. Data you are trying to store are a set of documents. Use a document store like couchDB or mongoDB. However, you since have to search this data, it is better to index this data in lucene which is built for such needs

Comment: Solr is actually based on lucene. It exposes it as a webservice among other things

Comment: Clearly I must read more about these databases. Before I do, is the following assumption correct ? I can store my books simply as f.x. pdf (or does it need to be BLOB ?) in these db´s, hook Solr or Lucene in front of it, have that system index my books and then just search through that system ? And if all of the previous is true, could the search somehow give me the page that the search finds relevant or will I have to store my books page by page to have that work ?

Comment: I do not think pdf can be stored directly into these DBs. They need to be processed to text and then indexed.

Comment: I assumed because you called them 'document store' that they would be able to store documents :) Do you have any advice for me on how to store the books if I need to be able to pull out individual pages ?

Comment: Document store => Document oriented storage. Traditionally databases have been used to store relational data. These data stores are, on the other hand, used for non relational data. Document is a general term here.

Comment: you can store them page wise or paragraph wise (and add some meta data per blob). To me para wise storage makes more sense as you can then show one para which logically makes more sense(a little) than page wise.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you don't intend to search the entire text of the book (perhaps consider initial processing to store a serialized hash of unique words?):

SQL Server 2008R2 has a new FILESTREAM system which will enforce relational integrity using the DB engine but will maintain the files in the file system.
It's the "best of both worlds" and you won't have to worry about how DB backup plans affects your BLOBs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: I was actually thinking of searching the entire text of the book if that is not too heavy of a process

Comment: Do you want to search them by exact phrases? Or will word search work? I'm wondering if you need to literally store the entire text of the book in a searchable field or if you can just use the unique words

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Foundation 2010 and 2013 could be your perfect solution which is absolutely free to use. You can store bulk amount of documents to different document libraries, add and edit their metadata, and search them using metadata like Title, Author, etc and even the text content inside the book.