# What schema, database, searching libraries are good for storing thousands of book pages in c# app

Tags: c#, database, search, lucene, schema

I want to write a **C#** program to store some books with the total of **5000 pages**. But there are a few important issues here that I need your help and advice:

1. The ability to search all of the books’ content is one of the most important and challenging features of the app. **The time that is needed to search a word should be about the time required to search a word in Microsoft Word or a PDF doc (with the same size) or more.**

   - What method should I employ for storing the books so that more suitable approaches to searching the content would be in hand? Relational DB, *MongoDB*, *couchDB*, etc. which one is preferred?
   - For the case of using Database, what kind of **Schema** and **indexing** is required and important?
   - Which method or algorithm or library is better to be used for searching the whole content of the books? Is it possible to use ***lucene*** or ***Solr*** in a standalone windows app or would traditional searching method be better?
2. The program should be customized in such a way that the **publisher** would be able to **add their own book contents**. How can I handle this feature (can I use **XML**)?
3. The users should be able to add one or more lines from the contents to their **favorite list**. What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but for sure you should use MongoDB,couchDB because they are document databases. About the searching you can use Solr, but I advise you to check Elasticseach. From what I know Solr is not supported anymore. About adding the books by the user, you should have some kind of import controller.

There is another question in stackoverflow about this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706503/storing-books-in-a-database

You can check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think Solr will be able to meet most of these requirements. For #1, you can easily develop schema in Solr to hold various information in different formats. Solr's Admin UI has an Analysis tab that will help you greatly in developing your schema because it allows you to test your changes on the fly with different types of data. It is a huge time saver because you don't have to create a bunch of test content and index it in to test it. Additionally, if the contents of the books are in binary format you can use Apache Tika to perform text extraction. Solr also has a number of other bells and whistles that you may find helpful, such as highlighting and user query spell suggestion.

For #2, Solr will support updates to content via JSON files that can be sent to the update handler for your collection. It also supports atomic updates which you may find useful. It seems that in your case, you may need some kind of a security solution to sit on top of Solr to prevent publishers from modifying each other's content, however you will most likely run into this issue regardless of the type of solution you will use.

For #3, I am not sure what you are really looking for here. I think that for content search and retrieval you will find Solr a good fit. For general user information storage and etc, you may need a different tool, since that is kind of outside of scope of what Solr is supposed to do.

Hope it helps.